# Why is my graph not coming out the way it should?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I was working on the code for one of the math classes I am taking this semester, and the math is coming out correctly, but I am not sure why the graph of the error term is not working out the way it should. This part of the project is for the Euler's explicit method, found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method). I need to be able to graph the error term as I go, which the graph is mostly coming out the way I would expect it would, but I am an extremely large error near the beginning which shouldn't happen. Of course, any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def Eulerm1(): 

    x0=0
    y0=2
    n=11
    xf=2
    x=np.linspace(x0,xf,n)
    y=np.zeros([n])
    z=(3+2*np.pi**2)/(1+np.pi**2)*np.e**x+((np.pi)/(1+np.pi**2))*np.sin(np.pi*x)+np.cos(np.pi*x)/(1+np.pi*x)
    L=[0]
    for i in range (1,n):
        deltax=(xf-x0)/(n-1)
        y[0]=y0
        y[i]=deltax*(np.cos(np.pi*x[i-1])+y[i-1])+y[i-1]
        z[i]=(3+2*np.pi**2)/(1+np.pi**2)*np.e**(x[i])+((np.pi)/(1+np.pi**2))*np.sin(np.pi*(x[i]))-np.cos(np.pi*(x[i]))/(1+np.pi**2)
        L.append(abs(y[i]-z[i]))
        b=abs(y[i]-z[i])
        print (x[i],y[i],z[i], abs(y[i]-z[i]))
        print(max(L))
        plt.plot(x,b)
        plt.xlabel('Time')
        plt.ylabel('Computational Errors')
        plt.title('Computational Errors with respect to Time')
        plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, you should really briefly describe what you are trying to do (instead of give a link), tells us what is wrong, and give a minimal example instead of letting us debug your whole project

Answer (score 0):

```
    for i in range (1,n):
        deltax=(xf-x0)/(n-1)
        y[0]=y0
        y[i]=deltax*(np.cos(np.pi*x[i-1])+y[i-1])+y[i-1]
        z[i]=(3+2*np.pi**2)/(1+np.pi**2)*np.e**(x[i])+((np.pi)/(1+np.pi**2))*np.sin(np.pi*(x[i]))-np.cos(np.pi*(x[i]))/(1+np.pi**2)
        L.append(abs(y[i]-z[i]))
        b=abs(y[i]-z[i])
        print (x[i],y[i],z[i], abs(y[i]-z[i]))
        print(max(L))
        plt.plot(x,b)

    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Computational Errors')
    plt.title('Computational Errors with respect to Time')
    plt.show()
```

your `plot.show()` was inside your for loop, so it rendered your graph on the first loop, and not after it was finished.